# how to input a number value once a button is pressed to a edit text box

Tags: android, jquery, math, button, android-edittext

Hi there I have 10 buttons numbered from 0 - 9 and i want to be able to assign those values to the buttons and input that value into the edit text box once i have pressed it. 
So far I've created the buttons and set on click listeners to them.
Thank you in advance for any help. :)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.eigth);
    Button q81 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb1);
    Button q82 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb2);
    Button q83 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb3);
    Button q84 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb4);
    Button q85 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb5);
    Button q86 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb6);
    Button q87 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb7);
    Button q88 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb8);
    Button q89 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb9);
    Button q80 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eightb0);

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText.getText();

    q81.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q82.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q83.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q84.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q85.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q86.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q87.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q88.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q89.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    q80.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `onClick()` method to do the following:

1. Get the character that was clicked.
2. Get the current text in the text field.
3. Append the clicked character.
4. Set the text field's string to the new string value.

Comment: Or merge steps 2-4 into one by calling `.append(...)` on the `TextView`. ;)